# PHP CMS Image Upload Error

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am trying to admin a site built in PHP. Currently, I am having an issue of not being able to upload media assets to it. The CMS returns an image upload error. What are the some of the things I can check on the server/CMS end to troubeshoot this? I checked permissions on the folder and it seems that Apache has all the required access.

Comment: which CMS are you using ?

Comment: Custom CMS is running on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this to htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

If not, upgrade to php version 5.

Comment: PHP has been upgraded to 5.6.12 recently. In fact, I have been wondering if this is a part of the problem. I looked through the release documentatioon and there does not seem to be anything related to file uploads.

Comment: Upgrade was 5.5.x -> 5.6.12

Comment: Also, I have tried adding this to web root and nothing changed. When I upload a rather large image, I can see the progress bar run. This makes me think that perhaps the problem is with DB. I believe the assets are stored in MongoDB in this CMS.